# Update iOS via Profile Manager as MDM

Tags: ios, macos, mdm

I use the Apple Profile Manager as a MDM solution for 100+ iPads. Distributing apps etc. does work perfectly but when it comes to updating iOS it is not that easy.

The iPads are all set to iOS Supervised Mode via the Apple Configurator 2, so the Profile Manager shows me that there are iOS Updates available. But when I try to install the Update via the Profile Manager the iPads only download the Updates but won't install them.

Did anyone else had the same problem and knows a solution to this? Or is it simply not possible to install the updates without touching the iPads?

Comment: Hi, did you figure out why this happened by any chance?

Comment: Hi @SochS. , unfortunately I could not solve this problem.